# Beans Scopes in Spring framework

Tags: spring, singleton, prototype, javabeans, scopes

I am new with Spring framework, If am creating two parent beans with prototype scope and inside I am creating two child beans inside parent beans with singleton scope. Then how many object will create?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever your parent beans are wired spring will create new instances everytime. However when spring wires the children beans to the parent the singleton instance of each child will be used.
Beans are singleton to the entire spring context and not to the objects they are wired in.

Hope that help you.
For more informafion on spring beans scope [read this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_bean_scopes.htm)